# Using IResult as return value for "classic" api instead of Minimal API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, minimal-apis

I have multiple services that return `IResult` and don´t want to use minimal API structure, but I want to use the same return type IResult, but when I use that in the controller it always returns Ok:

Minimal API example that returns 400 Bad request:

```
app.MapPut("test", async () =>
{
    return Results.BadRequest("hello");
});
```

The classic controller that returns 200 Ok:

```
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase

    [HttpPut("test")]
    public async Task<IResult> Test()
    {
        return Results.BadRequest();
    }
```

Is there an easy way to fix this or do I need a mapping function?

I am using .NET 6.

Comment: It would be handy to know which version of .NET you're using here. The answer you need varies from version to version.

Comment: Why do you want to use `IResult` in classic controllers though?

Comment: Thanks for adding the version of .NET you're using. In .NET 6, I think my answer should be accurate.

Comment: @Ethan except your post doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @DavidG how so? The easy way to fix that is to use the BadRequest() instead of Results.BadRequest(). I can clarify that if you want

Comment: Because then I can do this in my controller: return await TestService.DoStuff();

And the DoStuff method can return BadRequest if something is wrong

But when I think about it I might just throw an exception in DoStuff and make the ErrorController handle the return value

Comment: @Ethan It doesn't say how OP can use `IResult`, it uses a different type.

Comment: @Moddaman You shouldn't have your services know anything about HTTP stuff. Let them return a true/false/null/whatever of some sort and the controller is always responsible for the mapping to the  correct response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supported in .NET 7 now.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

public class Home : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("/")]
    public IResult Get() => Results.Ok("Okies");
}
```

Comment: And here is the documentation for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0#httpresults-type

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can call `IResult.ExecuteAsync` on the `ControllerBase`'s context:

```cs
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    public async Task SomeAction()
    {
        IResult result = Results.BadRequest(); // dummy result, use one from the service
        await result.ExecuteAsync(HttpContext);
    }
}
```

But in general it is better to follow standard patterns and in this case make your service return some custom app-specific response which is "platform-agnostic" i.e. it should not depend on web framework used and represent some business/domain related entity/data. Potentially you can look into some library which can represent "result" abstraction. For example [`FluentResults`](https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults) or go a bit more functional with some kind of `Either` (many options here [CSharpFunctionalExtensions](https://github.com/vkhorikov/CSharpFunctionalExtensions), [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext), [Optional](https://github.com/nlkl/Optional), etc.).

Comment: I seem to get a 401 response every time I try this request in .NET 6, even after changing the result to Results.Ok().

Comment: @Ethan it is strange, works fine "on my machine" .

Comment: Looks like I'm just a nitwit. Ignore me, you're right.

Comment: That worked. But you are correct. I changed my service to not use IResult and instead throw exceptionHandler deal with correct errors